# Make databound input textbox updateable with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with a bunch of labels and textboxes, my controller retrieves data and displays it in those controls:

```
 <label>ID: {{pageData.ID}}</label><br/>
 <label>Title: {{pageData.title}}</label></br>
 <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes" value="{{pageData.notes}}" />

 <input type="button" name="btnProcess" class="action-button" value="Process" ng-click="Process()" />
```

The display of the data works fine, but `notes` field is optional and in most cases is empty. I want to update the field ona  button-click.

Here is the code from my controller that pulls data into `PageData`:

```
$http.get(window.baseApiUrl + '/GetPageData').
        then(function (result) {             
            $scope.pageData = result.data;
        });
```

Now the issue is that for grabbing the value of `notes` textbox from my controller, I need `ng-model` but if I add `ng-model` to my textbox, I no longer able to see the values from the database for those records that do have notes.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Well, post your code. Have you populated the field that ngModel references with the value of the note? If the other fields must not be edited/updated, why do you use inputs to display them? I have the feeling you should start understanding how ng-model works. The single point of truth is the model. The view, thanks to ngModel displays what the model contains. You need to... have a model.

Comment: what do you mean by "If I add `ng-model` to my textbox, I no longer able to see the values from the database"?  that's what `ng-model` is for;  it's hard to see what other possibilities you might have without seeing a *complete* picture of your code, both the HTML and the JavaScript.

Comment: don't do `value="{{...}}"`...  That's not a "databound" input.

Comment: I added the code I use to pull data. basically the above works fine for displaying data but I want to allow the user to change the data in that one field

Comment: do you need the data persisted to the database after the user changes it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the `result.data` object?

Comment: you changed your other `inputs` to `labels` (breaking the question formatting in the process, btw.), but you still haven't explained why using `ng-model` makes it impossible to see what came from `$scope.pageData`.  if there is a `notes` property in `$scope.pageData`, then `ng-model="pageData.notes"` will display it, and changing this value will cause it to update the object in memory.  sending that update back to the server is a different matter....

Comment: I created a mockup of using `ng-model`, in hopes that you can explain why it doesn't do what you intend.  I seeded some fake data, then displayed it, and you can see that when you change the textbox and hit process, the data is indeed changed.  http://plnkr.co/edit/0hCK4QNhjxE9FaJikVDB?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly...
In your html change the ng-model of your text box:

```
<input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes" ng-model="pageData.notes" />
```

In your controller on your process function:

```
$scope.process = function() {
  //if you need data persisted to the database you'll call some api
  //endpoint here to send pageData to the server
  $http.put(window.baseApiUrl + '/UpdatePageData', $scope.pageData).
    then(function () {             
        console.log("data persisted");
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** Use ng-model to 2-way bind to pageData.notes.  This will display the value of pageData.note after your $http.get() and will also allow you to update the value of pageData.notes for you to post back to the server.

Comment: that is what I had previously but it only worked provided that `notes` field is empty in the database for that particular record

Comment: can you post more of your code? It's difficult to see what your end goal is.

Comment: @ElenaDBA are you trying to display the value of "pageData.notes" and be able to edit "pageData.notes" in the same input in the HTML?

Comment: @ElenaDBA, yes it is possible.  You would simply change ng-model to bind to pageData.notes.  Then in your put/post to the server, you would send the pageData object back.  Angular will 2-way bind with ng-model, so it will display the initial value of pageData.notes when pageData is populated, and it will also allow you to modify pageData.notes in the input field.